# Why my Program is showing this type of Error while iterating ArrayList using foreach loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, compiler-errors

[I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at com.cg.genuine.ui.ArrayLisPr.main(ArrayLisPr.java:12)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayLisPr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] x={11,20,3,4,5};
        List<Integer> po = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(x));
        for(Integer val:po){
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a single object, which is an `int[]`, and as such, can't be cast to an `Integer`. If you remove the intermediate variable and use `Arrays.asList` directly, Java will be able to autobox each `int` to an `Integer` individually:

```
List<Integer> po = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(11,20,3,4,5));
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep the `int[]` reference, you'll have to convert it to a `List<Integer>` manually. One way to do so is to stream it and box all the elements:

```
List<Integer> po = Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What if I want to convert Integer Array to ArrayList using its Array Object reference?

Comment: @RituRajShrivastava you'll have to convert it yourself. See my edited answer for the details.

Comment: `List<Integer> po = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(11,20,3,4,5))`  could be simplified to `List<Integer> po = Arrays.asList(11,20,3,4,5)`